# How do I make a program that I have already created run after I press a button in a different program that I have made?

Tags: java, swing, button, execute

I'm doing a project where I need 4 buttons and each button will perform a different mathematical function of some sort. I have all of the functions written in programs separate from the program with the buttons.

I'm going to just use a sample program that I made in NetBeans instead of posting the whole code on my actual project.

```
public class NewJPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    /**
     * Creates new form NewJPanel
     */
    public NewJPanel() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        jTextField1.setText("jTextField1");

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");

        jButton2.setText("jButton2");

        jButton3.setText("jButton3");
        jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(27, 27, 27)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jButton1)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jButton2)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jButton3))
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap(79, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(29, 29, 29)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 149, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addComponent(jButton2)
                    .addComponent(jButton3))
                .addGap(78, 78, 78))
        );
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
      // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

So that is the program with the buttons. Now how would I execute a program called Celsius after pressing one of the JButtons?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Please use code formatting for code, input/output & structured documents like HTML or XML.  To do that, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form.

Answer (score 10):

You must not reason in terms of programs starting other programs, but in terms of classes using other classes.

So let's say your Celsius program has a Celsius class with the method

```
int convertToFahrenheit(int celsiusDegrees)
```

Your program will make sure to have the jar file of the celsius program, containing the Celsius class, in its classpath, and will simply use, when a button is clicked

```
Celsius celsius = new Celsius();
int fahrenheit = celsius.convertToFehrenheit(someCelsiusDegrees);
```

So, to be short, the celsius program will become a library used by your new Swing program.

Comment: +1 I think the first sentence of your explanation is rather important.

Comment: OK I think I understand what you're saying But how would I use ActionClass or whatever to use the library when I press the button.

Comment: Replace `// TODO add your handling code here:` by the code you want to execute when the button 3 is clicked. And read the [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/), because using the drag n' drop Netbeans interface without understanding what you're doing won't lead you anywhere. I would advise to avoid these wysiwyg tools, at lest until you perfectly understand what they're doing for you.

Comment: Like copy and paste the entire code? I cant just have the program look it up somehow? I just found out that the due date for my project was changed to tomorrow so I'm in a rush to finish this otherwise I would go through that tutorial.

Comment: No, not copy and paste the entire code. Just calling your Celsius class as explained in the lest part of my answer. I can't understand why your teacher makes you program a Swing app if it hasn't taught your classes and methods yet.

Comment: It's because this guy is a lazy jackass. I've had to teach myself everything about java up to this point and I'm pretty stuck now. Thanks for the reply though.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;

public class CallHelloPgm
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      Process theProcess = null;
      BufferedReader inStream = null;



      // call the Hello class
      try
      {
          theProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java someProgram"); // Your magic line
      }
      catch(IOException e)
      {
         System.err.println("Error on exec() method");
         e.printStackTrace();  
      }

      // read from the called program's standard output stream
      try
      {
         inStream = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader( theProcess.getInputStream() ));  
         System.out.println(inStream.readLine());
      }
      catch(IOException e)
      {
         System.err.println("Error on inStream.readLine()");
         e.printStackTrace();  
      }


       } // end method

    } // end class
```